# Finding children of a GtkWidget

Tags: gtk, ui-automation

I need to be able to explore a GTK GUI's structure programmatically. I have the GtkWidget and I want to find any children of that widget. Now I know that GtkContainer's have a function to find children and that GtkContainer is derived from GtkWidget.

Is there anyway I can check if a widget is a GtkContainer and then perform the cast? If not, is there any other way I can discover the GtkWidget's that are children of the one I have?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20461465/2015768

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there are macros for every GObject type to check whether an object is of that type:

```
if(GTK_IS_CONTAINER(widget)) {
    GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(widget));
    ...
}
```

If the widget is a `GtkBin` it has only one child. In that case, the following is simpler than dealing with a `GList`:

```
if(GTK_IS_BIN(widget)) {
    GtkWidget *child = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(widget));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the following code I have implemented `find_child` function which recursively searches for the widget by name. Ideas build on the answer of @ptomato and from the [following](http://cdn.php-gtk.eu/cdn/farfuture/qhfV7w4H8PYVGWXg6RN8OePc35RA1QDNrujbEk8Twg0/mtime:1368022411/sites/php-gtk.eu/files/gtk-php-get-child-widget-by-name.php__0.txt) PHP example:

```c
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    GtkWidget*
    find_child(GtkWidget* parent, const gchar* name)
    {
            if (g_strcasecmp(gtk_widget_get_name((GtkWidget*)parent), (gchar*)name) == 0) { 
                    return parent;
            }

            if (GTK_IS_BIN(parent)) {
                    GtkWidget *child = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(parent));
                    return find_child(child, name);
            }

            if (GTK_IS_CONTAINER(parent)) {
                    GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));
                    while ((children = g_list_next(children)) != NULL) {
                            GtkWidget* widget = find_child(children->data, name);
                            if (widget != NULL) {
                                    return widget;
                            }
                    }
            }

            return NULL;
    }

    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
            gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

            GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
            GtkWidget *frame = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
            GtkWidget *vbox1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
            GtkWidget *textView = gtk_text_view_new();
            GtkWidget *hbox1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
            GtkWidget *button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button1");
            gtk_widget_set_name(button1, "btn1");
            GtkWidget *button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button2");
            gtk_widget_set_name(button2, "btn2");

            gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello");
            gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
            gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 450, 400);

            gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);
            gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame), vbox1);

            gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox1), textView, 1, 1, 0);
            gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox1), hbox1, 0, 1, 0);
            gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), button1, 0, 1, 0);
            gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox1), button2, 0, 1, 0);

            gtk_widget_show_all(window);

            g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

            GtkWidget* child = find_child(window, "btn2");
            if (child == button2) {
                    g_print("found it!\n");
            } else {
                    g_print("not found it!\n");
            }

            gtk_main();
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it was very helpful and helped me solve my problem. However, I found one bug I wanted to share with people who use it: because in find_child you call gtk_container_get_children() and then immediately call g_list_next_children(), you never explore the first node in the tree. I fixed this with a do/while loop, although you still need to be sure the first item isn't NULL.

Comment: This code has subtle bug:  In the GTK_IS_CONTAINER part of find_child, you iterate over the children in "while ((children == g_list_next()" loop.  This is wrong, it skips the first child!

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `GTK_IS_BIN`. Is it gone? If so, how do we check the widget's type?

Comment: Update: You can get the glib Type, get its parent, and check if it's a bin.

Answer (score 0):

I created these functions that are based on the same principal as the accepted answer.

In `find_child_by_index`, `depth` is equal to the amount of indices you need to pass. The first index is for the children of `parent`, the second index is for the grandchildren and so forth.

```c
void print_children_helper(GtkWidget* parent, int indent_size, int depth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < depth * indent_size; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%s\n", gtk_widget_get_name(parent));

    GList* children = NULL;
    if (GTK_IS_CONTAINER(parent))
        children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));

    while (children != NULL)
    {
        print_children(children->data, indent_size, depth + 1);
        children = children->next;
    }
}

void print_children(GtkWidget* parent, int indent_size)
{
    print_children_helper(parent, indent_size, 0);
}

GtkWidget* find_child_by_name(GtkWidget* parent, const gchar* name)
{
    if (g_strcmp0(gtk_widget_get_name(parent), name) == 0)
        return parent;

    GList* children = NULL;
    if (GTK_IS_CONTAINER(parent))
        children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));

    while (children != NULL)
    {
        GtkWidget* widget = find_child_by_name(children->data, name);

        if (widget != NULL)
            return widget;

        children = children->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

GtkWidget* find_child_by_index(GtkWidget* parent, int depth, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, depth);

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    {
        int index = va_arg(argp, int);

        GList* children = NULL;
        if (GTK_IS_CONTAINER(parent))
            children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));

        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++)
            if (children != NULL)
                children = children->next;

        if (children != NULL)
            parent = children->data;
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    va_end(argp);
    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is needed if using GTK4 as GtkContainer no longer exists. See [migration guide](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#switch-to-gtkwidgets-children-apis)

A simple function traversing the widget heirarchy:

```
void print_widget_names(GtkWidget* parent, int level) {
  for (int i=0; i < level; i++) { 
    g_print("    ");
  }
  level++;
  g_print("%s\n", gtk_widget_get_name(GTK_WIDGET(parent)));
  GtkWidget *widget = gtk_widget_get_first_child(GTK_WIDGET(parent));
  GtkWidget *next;
  if (widget != NULL) {
    print_widget_names(widget, level);
    while ((next = gtk_widget_get_next_sibling(widget)) != NULL) {
      widget = next;
      print_widget_names(widget, level);
    }
  }
}
```