# GTK+ 2 change label color of GtkCheckButton

Tags: c, gtk

I would like to change the default label color of a GtkCheckButton. I surely need to access its GtkContainer or GtkBin and iterate through its children.
However, I have not found any code to do this.

I have:

```
GtkWidget* myCheckbox = gtk_check_button_new_with_label("Hello");

GdkColor color;
gdk_color_parse ("#FF0000", &color);
gtk_widget_modify_fg (myCheckbox, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
```

But it modifies just the border's color.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this code works:

```
if(GTK_IS_BIN(myCheckbox)) {
        GtkWidget *child = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(myCheckbox));
        GdkColor color;
        gdk_color_parse ("#FF0000", &color);
        gtk_widget_modify_fg (child, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
    }
```

The idea came from [Finding children of a GtkWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401327/finding-children-of-a-gtkwidget).

HTH